# why does this not work??? It is on python:

Tags: python

```
import csv
names = ["jeff","tony"]
scores = []
number = 0
if number == 0:
    file = open("Class A.txt", 'r')
    for line in file:
        names.append(names)   #
        scores.append(scores)
        number = number + 1
    f = open ("Class A.csv", 'a')
    for x in names:
        f.write (x)
        f.write ("\n")
    for x in scores:
        f.write (x)
        f.write ("\n")
```

the line with the '#' is the line that is causing problems
help will be much appreciated

Comment: `names.append(names)`???

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Provide the input csv file example

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you wanted to do this:

```
if number == 0:
    file = open("Class A.txt", 'r')
    for line in file:
        name, score = line.split(', ', 2) # split line into name and score
        names.append(name)   # name instead of names
        scores.append(score) # score instead of scores
        number = number + 1
```

assuming your Data looks like:

```
NAME1, SCORE1
NAME2, SCORE2 
etc.
```

Comment: there is now a problem with:

Comment: new problem: f.write (x)

Comment: scores.append(scores)

Comment: It seems like the code should magically read the file and split the information into names and scores :)